# matlab 2015a 64 bit installation issue on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, java, matlab

I'm having trouble with matlab 2015a (64 bit version) installation on ubuntu 14.04. I did chmod things to make install file(in the root directory) executable and after running it these messages were shown in terminal:

Preparing installation files ...
Installing ...
Finished

I expected to see java GUI installer and go ahead with installation but nothing happened anymore!

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `./install -v` to get verbose output of what's going on and run last command(s) you see on your own. You should get some kind of error to your stderr/stdout.

I had the same problem, in my case their bundled java refused to run from tmp directory saying "Permission denied", because my `/tmp` directory is actually in RAM (tmpfs).
The simplest workaround is to specify custom tmp dir i.e.

`sudo ./install -tmpdir ~/disktmp/` (of course you should create `~/disktmp` dir first and give it correct permissions)

The other way around is described here: http://serialized.net/2010/03/getting-around-tmpfs-noexec-problems/

Answer (score 0):

that is the only solution that worked for me:

```
sudo su
chmod 777 -R /home/yourUSER/pathTO/matlabFOLDER
cd /home/yourUSER/pathTO/matlabFOLDER
./install
```

from:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=50gryiqkgxw